# Bootstrap 3 Modal; scrollTop when Collapse (accordion) opened

Tags: jquery, accordion, bootstrap-modal

I have a page (Bootstrap 3) that opens a modal. There are groups of Collapse panels (accordions) on the modal. I would like to have the page scrollTop when the collapse headers are clicked open. Javascript that has been tried (using ScrollTo plugin for this sample):

```
$('.panel').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   var panel = $(this).find('.in');
   var mtop = $(this).closest('.modal.in');
   $.scrollTo(mtop.offset().top-25, 350);
});
```

The window behind the modal will scrollTop. Through the console I can get the modal to scrollTop a certain number of pixels. Just can't seem to figure out how to target the collapse that is opened. Any help/ideas appreciated.

Comment: Please relook at this line:    $.scrollTo(mtop.offset().top-25, 350);

Comment: Create a Jsfiddle if possible also, buddy.

Comment: OK, I've made a simplified fiddle for this. I changed the javascript a bit, but tries to accomplish the same thing generally. https://jsfiddle.net/jhottle/2z4ncp4u/